# #pragma pack won't compile?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile some downloaded source which contains lots of:

```
142    #ifdef __cplusplus
143    #pragma pack(1)
144    #endif
```

but I get the following error and it won't compile:

```
src/globals.h:143:16: error: expected declaration before end of line
mingw32-make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 1
```

I'm using a makefile downloaded with the rest of the source to compile it.

what do I need to do to get this to compile?

**EDIT**:

The source code is the code for [KeeperFX](http://keeper.lubie.org/html/dk_keeperfx_dwnld.php) available from [google code](https://code.google.com/p/keeperfx/source/checkout).

Comment: What compiler version are you using? I think support for this was added in GCC 4.0, and MinGW 3.4.5 is still in pretty common use.

Comment: I downloaded MinGW today and I'm using GCC 4.5

Comment: I am wondering why you would only pack when using C++ code!?

Comment: `error: expected declaration before end of line` can't possibly refer directly to the #pragma line, post the related code (src/globals.h, line 143).

Comment: @clifford: I've added a link to the source code.

Comment: @Clifford: your comment above solved this... There was another error (I was attempting to fix both) and this error disappeared when I fixed the other.

Comment: @JamesB:  There was only one error from the compiler, the other error was from the make utility. Error 1 from make simply means the build failed, i.e. an executed command returned a non-zero value; the executed command being the compiler invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have absolutely no idea why GCC picked on pragma pack to highlight it's issue the actual problem was that it was trying to compile a Version.h resource (Version resource information) as code. The compile was failing and just decided to spit out a completely irrelevant error.

Answer (score 1):

As I know #pragma directives belongs to the Microsoft C++ Compiler. GCC [supports some of these directives](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html), but MinGW does not.

Comment: That's not true, there are a few standardised `#pragma` directives, specifically those that start with `#pragma STDC`. However, using `#pragma` usually makes your source code less portable, since a compiler is free to interpret it or ignore it however it wants (provided it is not a standardised directive).

Comment: @dreamlax: "Standardised" and "implemented" are two different things.  For example the "Status of C99 features in GCC" statement http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html says *Standard Pragmas: Missing*, and VC++ makes no claims for C99 support at all (and probably never will).

Comment: #pragma is not specific to VC++, however specific pragma directives *are* compiler dependent.  The required behaviour of a compiler encountering an unknown #pragma is to ignore it. Most compilers will issue at least a warning.

Comment: @Clifford: Of course standardised and implemented are two different things, I was arguing the fact that #pragma directives are not specific [nor do they exclusively belong to] Microsoft's compiler suite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GCC [`__attribute__((packed))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes) extension.

Comment: as I understand it (very little), I would need the `__attribute__ ((aligned))`? where presumably `__attribute__ ((aligned(1)))` would be equivilent to packed?